# Accessing image chunk by chunk in parallel

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, gdal

I got the following code to derive an index from a multiband image. Because my image is large, I had to process it chunk by chunk. Now I would like to turn it to a parallel for loop to do it faster. I've seen there are libraries (eg ParallelProcessing) to do it but I've trouble to translate it into my case... Any idea?
The data can be find at http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_data5.zip

```
import os, sys, numpy, gdal, utils2
from gdalconst import *

os.chdir('c:/temp/py5')

# register all of the GDAL drivers
gdal.AllRegister()

# open the image
inDs = gdal.Open('aster.img', GA_ReadOnly)
if inDs is None:
  print 'Could not open aster.img'
  sys.exit(1)

# get image size
rows = inDs.RasterYSize
cols = inDs.RasterXSize
bands = inDs.RasterCount

# get the bands and block sizes
inBand2 = inDs.GetRasterBand(2)
inBand3 = inDs.GetRasterBand(3)
blockSizes = utils2.GetBlockSize(inBand2)
xBlockSize = blockSizes[0]
yBlockSize = blockSizes[1]
print yBlockSize, xBlockSize

# create the output image
driver = inDs.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create('ndvi.img', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Float32)
if outDs is None:
  print 'Could not create ndvi.img'
  sys.exit(1)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)

# loop through the rows
for i in range(0, rows, yBlockSize):
  if i + yBlockSize < rows:
    numRows = yBlockSize
  else:
    numRows = rows - i

  # loop through the columns
  for j in range(0, cols, xBlockSize):
    if j + xBlockSize < cols:
      numCols = xBlockSize
    else:
      numCols = cols - j

    # read the data in
    data2 = inBand2.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows).astype(numpy.Float16)
    data3 = inBand3.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows).astype(numpy.Float16)

    # do the calculations
    mask = numpy.greater(data2 + data3, 0)
    ndvi = numpy.choose(mask, (-99, (data3 - data2) / (data3 + data2)))

    # write the data
    outBand.WriteArray(ndvi, j, i)

# flush data to disk, set the NoData value and calculate stats
outBand.FlushCache()
outBand.SetNoDataValue(-99)
stats = outBand.GetStatistics(0, 1)

# georeference the image and set the projection
outDs.SetGeoTransform(inDs.GetGeoTransform())
outDs.SetProjection(inDs.GetProjection())

# build pyramids
gdal.SetConfigOption('HFA_USE_RRD', 'YES')
outDs.BuildOverviews(overviewlist=[2,4,8,16,32,64,128])

inDs = None
outDs = None
```

Comment: But if you use, for instance, 8 processes in parallel you would need to have in memory 8 times more space to store the input and the output. Am I right? Would this be a problem?

Comment: no because the chunks all together don't have to be as big as the entire image